# Make a recursive Stream from just 1 element?

Tags: scala, recursion, stream

I've made a Stream for [Gray Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) using recursion as follows:

```
val gray: Stream[List[String]] = {
 List("") #:: List("0", "1") #:: gray.tail.map {gnext} 
}
```

where

```
val gnext = (i:List[String]) => i.map {"0" + _} ::: i.reverse.map {"1" + _}
```

so that, for example

```
scala> gray(2)
res17: List[String] = List(00, 01, 11, 10)
```

I don't really need the List("0", "1") in the definition, because it can be produced from element 0:

```
scala> gnext(List(""))
res18: List[java.lang.String] = List(0, 1)
```

So is there a way / pattern that can be used to produce a Stream from just the first element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val gray: Stream[List[String]] = List("") #:: gray.map {gnext}
```

Or, alternatively,

```
val gray = Stream.iterate(List(""))(gnext)
```

Comment: Cool, just use the whole list instead of the tail. Would I be right in saying that the first version would be memoized, but the version with `iterate` would not?

Comment: @Luigi neither `gray` is a function, so I don't think memoization applies.

Comment: Good point - they're both Stream objects. As I understand it, `Stream`s are lazy `List`s, so if I reference `gray(10)` on a new `gray` object it will take a long time, but if I then reference `gray(8)` it will be instant, because that value was already computed. So it is like automatic memoization.